# Explicitly setting/ignoring visibility at design-time in VS2013?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013

I'm designing a form for a complex backing model in WPF. Some of the form controls rely on multiple options being set on the underlying view model, so I've set up for example

```
<TextBlock.Visibility>
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AndMultiValueVisibilityConverter}">
    <Binding Path="RelevantSystemOption" />
    <Binding Path="RelevantLicenseKeyOption"/>
  </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Visibility>
```

AndMultiValueVisibilityConverter takes booleans and only makes something visible if they're all true, for reference.

This turns the control's visibility off at design time, which I don't want.

I'm aware of the ability of [Expression Blend and design-time attributes](https://wpftutorial.net/DesigntimeVsRuntime.html) to make certain layout determinations that can be ignored at run-time. d:IsHidden isn't being respected, and d:LayoutOverrides doesn't work on Visibility since it's a dynamic property.

I'd rather not dummy up an entire backing model with d:DataContext. I will if I have to, but is there an easier way to just force this particular control and maybe a handful of others to always be visible at design-time?

Comment: use `DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject())` in your multivalue converter.

Comment: Yeah, that works out well. Did you mean that to be a comment?

Comment: I'd have closed this as a duplicate (which is perfectly fine and normal) if I could find a decent canonical question, but I can't.  So, meh, answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject())
```

in your multivalue converter to determine if you're in the designer and, if so, return true.

It's okay to use this in a converter in an MVVM application, if you think it might go against the pattern. The converter is a UI concern.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties(v=vs.110).aspx